# Update/Delete syntax error in rails 6 sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Why is rails db acting different than the runtime sql?

created a new application using rvm 1.29.11; Rails 6.1.1; ruby 3.0.0p0; sqlite3 3.28.0.  Generated simple scaffold rails g s name phone.  migrated db (rails db:migrate).  App fires and runs.  Able to create, update, and delete records.  However, when I try to run the command executed using rails db I get the following error:

```
app/controllers/stores_controller.rb:67:in `set_store'
  TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/stores_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'
  Store Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "stores" SET "phone" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "stores"."id" = ?  [["phone", "1234"], ["updated_at", "2021-01-10 21:39:51.295940"], ["id", 2]]
  ↳ app/controllers/stores_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'
  TRANSACTION (1.5ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/stores_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3001/stores/2
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms | Allocations: 3248)
```

from rails db

```
 rails db
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-15 14:49:49
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>  UPDATE "stores" SET "phone" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "stores"."id" = ?  [["phone", "1234"], ["updated_at", "2021-01-10 21:39:51.295940"], ["id", 2]];
Error: near "[["phone", "1234"]": syntax error
sqlite> .quit
```

Why is rails db acting different that the run time sql?  I am doing a copy/paste from the dev log to the db:console and just adding the terminating ";"?

Answer (score 1):

`rails db` is not a Rails console, it is the *console for your SQL database*. In this case the [SQLite command line](https://sqlite.org/cli.html). Ruby and Rails commands will not work here, only SQL and SQLite commands. `["phone", "1234"]` is Ruby.

The Rails console is `rails console` or just `rails c`. This accepts Ruby.

`UPDATE "stores" SET "phone" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "stores"."id" = ?  [["phone", "1234"], ["updated_at", "2021-01-10 21:39:51.295940"], ["id", 2]]` will work in neither. This is neither SQL nor Rails. It's debugging output and it needs to be interpreted a bit.

`UPDATE "stores" SET "phone" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "stores"."id" = ?` is the SQL with placeholders for the values.

`[["phone", "1234"], ["updated_at", "2021-01-10 21:39:51.295940"], ["id", 2]]` are pairs of columns and their values.

Put them together and you get the SQL statement:

```
UPDATE "stores"
SET "phone" = '1234',
    "updated_at" = '2021-01-10 21:39:51.295940'
WHERE "stores"."id" = 2
```

This you can run in the SQLite console.

Comment: Thank you, Schwem, for you response.  You are correct in pointing out that I was imprecise in the terminology of Rails Console.  I know that rails db opens the sql db in terminal mode and I used the wrong terms.  However, in earlier versions of RoR, the sql statements in the dev log could be copy/pasted and would run.  I was confused by the current operation.  Again, thanks for your response.

Comment: @user3754107 If you figure out how to run those more directly, please let me know.